# Bootstrap only showing navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just started studying about bootstrap an hour ago and I thought it would be a breeze. I'm trying to convert it the typical CSS style to bootstrap but it's giving me quite a problem, the only content that is showing is the navigation bar.

This is my code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require 'config.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Processors</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Fonts.css">
    <link href="Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="Bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="Bootstrap/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Bootstrap/js/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-custom" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand"><img src="Images/Nav/logo.png" width="30px"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse av navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="case.php">CASE</a></li>
                <li><a href="accessories.php">ACCCESSORIES</a></li>
                <li><a href="peripherals.php">PERIPHERALS</a></li>
                <li><a href="hdd.php">STORAGE</a></li>
                <li><a href="psu.php">POWER SUPPLY</a></li>
                <li><a href="graphicCard10xx.php">GRAPHIC CARD</a></li>
                <li><a href="memory.php">MEMORY</a></li>
                <li><a href="motherboard.php">MOTHERBOARD</a></li>
                <li><a href="processor.php">PROCESSOR</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="search.php"><img src="Images/Nav/searchIco.png" width="22px"></a></li>
                <li><a href="cart.php"><img src="Images/Nav/cartIco.png" width="22px"></a></li>
                <li><a href="login.php"><img src="Images/Nav/userIco.png" width="22px"></a><li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav> <!-- nav End --> 
    <p style="color: black">
        ASDGASDFASDFDASFADSFASDASDGASDFASDFDASFADSFASDASDGASDFASDFDASFADSFASDASDGASDFASDFDASFADSFASDASDGASDFASDFDASFADSFASDASDGASDFASDFDASFADSFASDASDGASDFASDFDASFADSFASDASDGASDFASDFDASFADSFASDASDGAS
    </p>
</body> 
</html>
```

I made only VERY light modifications to the navigation bar which I dont think is the problem, but I am going to put it here anyway just in case

```
.navbar {
    background: #1f63aa;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: navBarFont;
    src: url(../Fonts/BGT.ttf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Calibri;
    src: url(../Fonts/Calibri.ttf);
}

.navbar-default a {
    font-family: navBarFont;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: white;
}

.navbar-nav li a {
    color: #fff !important; 
}

.navbar-nav li a:hover {
    color: #dddddd !important; 
}

.navbar-toggle {
    background-color: #1f63aa !important;
    border: 0px;
}

.icon-bar {
    background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

See this JSFiddle for an example: https://jsfiddle.net/5o4orrLo/1/

Comment: Consider adding a jsFiddle demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have used `.navbar-fixed-top` class for navbar which make it fixed position so your other text is hidden below it. if you don't need fixed navbar, remove it. else wrap `<p>` with some `<div>` and add `padding-top` equal the height of navbar.